# Code is adding backslash before apostrophe

Tags: php, apostrophe

For example I writed this text is **I don't know** and submited it to database.
Then I go to page, where this text appears and it show **I don\'t know**, how can I disable adding backslashes?

code

```
$text= htmlspecialchars($db['text']);
$textA = array('/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is');
$textB = array('<b>$1</b>'); 
$textC = preg_replace($textA,$textB,$text);
echo nl2br($textC);
```

Answer (score 2):

Turn off [magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) and make sure you are not using [addslashes](http://php.net/addslashes) before saving to the database

Answer (score 1):

Turn **magic_quotes** off in your `.htaccess` file by adding this line:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Comment: htmlspecialchars doesn't escape apostrophes. This is most likely magic quotes.

Comment: You're kidding? wrap stripslashes into the htmlspecialchars function? Why not just turn off magiq_quotes_gpc since he doesn't want the escaping? Sometimes I get so confused.